# Location of Intern reporters output files like corbertura or html report

Tags: gruntjs, intern

I'm using Grunt with Intern and set some reporters to `lcovhtml` and `cobertura`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        intern: {
            runner: {
                options: {
                    config: 'tests/intern',
                    runType: 'runner',
                    reporters: ['pretty', 'lcovhtml','junit','cobertura']
                }
            }
        },
```

Is there any configuration to control output directory of these files for all or each reporter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, by adding a parameters `reportDir` to the `options` object defined in your **Gruntfile.js**, you can update **intern/lib/reporters/lcovhtml.js** with:

```
define([
    'dojo/node!istanbul/lib/collector',
    'dojo/node!istanbul/lib/report/html',
    'dojo/node!istanbul/index'
], function (Collector, Reporter) {
    var collector = new Collector(),
        reporter = new Reporter();
    //...
});
```

with:

```
define([
    '../args',
    'dojo/node!istanbul/lib/collector',
    'dojo/node!istanbul/lib/report/html',
    'dojo/node!istanbul/index'
], function (args, Collector, Reporter) {
    var collector = new Collector(),
        reporter = new Reporter({ dir: args.reportDir });
    //...
});
```

You can propagate a similar update in **cobertura.js** and **junit.js** reporters.

*Note: I documented this approach in https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/71. The patch for the corresponding issue has not yet been published (pushed to Intern 2.3).*

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Dom! Link here for which pull request will handle the config updates that people can subscribe to. This will be available in Intern 3: https://github.com/theintern/intern/pull/181